# How do I increase the "global memory" available to the Intel CPU OpenCL driver?

Tags: memory, opencl, cpu, intel, amd-processor

My system has 32GB of ram, but the device information for the Intel OpenCL implementation says "CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE: 2147352576" (~2GB).

I was under the impression that on a CPU platform the global memory is the "normal" ram and thus something like ~30+GB should be available to the OpenCL CPU implementation. (ofcourse I'm using the 64bit version of the SDK)

Is there some sort of secret setting to tell the Intel OpenCL driver to increase global memory and use all the system memory ?

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, are you using a 64-bit OS?  My i5 with 8GB shows the correct amount with the Intel OpenCL SDK.

Comment: Sure, I'm using Windows 7 64bit. To rule out Intel specific driver bugs I've installed the AMD OpenCL SDK and it also shows only ~2GB. At least it's good to know that it is indeed possible to use the complete address space, but it still remains a mystery to me why I can't use more than ~2GB.

Comment: What is your processor version?  Mine is a 2nd or 3rd gen i5-2400.

Comment: Sorry, another dumb question, when using glGetDeviceInfo, are you passing unsigned long and not a uint or int?

Comment: If you solved your problem, you should write an answer and accept it to communicate that answer instead of writing the solution in the question

Comment: Just did that! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: Got it working by recompiling everything to 64bit. Quite stupid as it seems, but I thought that OpenCL was working similar to OpenGL, where you can easily allocate e.g. 8GB texture memory from a 32bit process and the driver handles the details for you (ofcourse you can't allocate 8GB in one sweep, but e.g. transfer multiple textures that add up to more that 4GB).

I still think that limiting the OpenCL memory abstraction to the adress space of the process (at least for intel/amd drivers) is irritating, but maybe there are some subtle details or performance tradeoff why this implementation was chosen.